# Laser Rangefinder, Water

Tags: water, laser

I don't understand how laser rangefinders work, and wiki does not have a clear answer on this.
Can a laser rangefinder measure distance up to water surface? Or will it go through the water and measure the bottom of.. lets say my bathtub?

Answer (score 1):

Laser rangefinders work by sending out a signal and recording the time that it takes for the reflected signal to be detected. If $t$ is the time from when you hit the button to when the light is detected, the distance (assuming we are measuring through air) is given by
$$d_{air} = \frac{1}{2}ct$$
Where $c$ is the speed of light (it is approximately the same in a vacuum as in air).

However, in a medium, the speed of light is given by $v = \frac{c}{n}$, where $n$ is the refractive index of the medium. So if the distance is being measured entirely through the medium, the distance is
$$d = \frac{ct}{2n}$$

If we were to use the rangefinder underwater, it would still do the calculation using the first expression and display an incorrect value. This value is not useless though, as we may rewrite the general expression in terms of the distance through air (which is what the rangefinder displays)
$$d = \frac{d_{air}}{n}$$

This means that if you divide the displayed value by the refractive index of the water (at room temperature $n_{water} = 1.33$) you will be able to correctly calculate the distance through water.

Comment: ...but it will not detect the distance to the surface...it is likely to pass through. I guess that's what the OP also wants to know

Answer (score 0):

Laser rangefinders measure distance by sending a laser pulse to a target and measuring the time it takes for the reflection to return. When measuring a water surface, the laser typically reflects off the surface, allowing the device to measure the distance to the water's surface. However, the laser's effectiveness can vary based on the angle of incidence and the water's clarity. In most cases, it will not penetrate deep enough to measure the bottom of something like a bathtub; it will measure the distance to the surface of the water.